Finding lengths in a figure where segment through vertex and incentre is extended to circumcircle
Question: Given a triangle $ABC$ with area $360$ and perimeter $90$, such that its incircle is centered at $I$. Point $D$ is drawn on the triangle’s circumcircle such that $AD$ passes through $I$ and intersects $BC$ at $E$. Find $DE$ if $CD = 10$.


Here's what I've done:

The inradius of $\triangle ABC$ is $8$.
By the incentre-excentre lemma, $BD=DC=ID=10$.
By the inscribed angle theorem, if we let $AB=c$ and $AC=b$, then $BE=kc$ and $CE=kb$ for some constant $k$.

Using Heron's formula yields $$360=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} (ka+kb+a+b)(ka+kb+a-b)(ka+kb+b-a)(b+a-ka-kb)}$$
Considering the perimeter yields $$a+b+ka+kb=90$$
Considering the fact that $\triangle AEC \sim \triangle BED$ yields $$\frac{AE}{BE}=\frac{AC}{BD} \implies \frac{\sqrt{ab-abk^2}}{ka}=\frac{b}{10}$$ ($AE=\sqrt{ab-abk^2}$ by Stewart's theorem)
Solving this system using Wolfram Alpha yields $$b \approx 26.8146, c \approx 43.4318, k \approx 0.281204$$
Considering the fact that $\triangle AEC \sim \triangle BED$ again yields $$\frac{DE}{CE}=\frac{BD}{AC} \implies DE=\frac{10 \cdot kb}{b}=10k \approx 2.81204$$
However, I would like to find an exact answer if possible, and I also know that my approach is extremely ugly. Any help would be appreciated!

That triangle cannot exist.
Let $h$ be the altitude from $A$ to base $BC$. As the area of triangle $ABC$ is $360$ we get:
$$
BC\cdot h=720,
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
BC={720\over h}.
$$
We also know that the perimeter of $ABC$ is $90$, hence:
$$
AB+AC=90-{720\over h}.
$$
But $AB\ge h$ and $AC\ge h$, hence we get the inequality:
$$
90-{720\over h}\ge2h,
$$
which can be solved to get:
$$
{45-\sqrt{585}\over2}\le h\le {45+\sqrt{585}\over2}.
$$
On the other hand, we know that $BD=CD=10$ in triangle $BCD$, which entails
$BC<20$. But then:
$$
h={720\over BC}>{720\over20}=36.
$$
This contradicts our previous estimate, as ${45+\sqrt{585}\over2}\approx 34.6$. Hence the given setting is impossible.
